# Varias declaraciones en un trigger phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando lograr que mi trigger haga esta funcion pero me manda este error.
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 3
este es mi codigo del trigger

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `act_pedido` BEFORE INSERT ON `vta_ped_lin_g`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE vta_ped_lin_g SET NUM_LIN = @contador WHERE ID=834;
 SET @contador = (SELECT COUNT(ID) from vta_ped_lin_g WHERE VTA_PED=VTA_PED);
 END;
```

Comment: Estás usando delimiters?

Comment: no no conozco de eso que es?

Comment: funciono muchas gracias